# How do i append at a json file at the end of the list with python

Tags: python, json

So i want to put some json strings like this

```
[{"username": "username", "key": "key"}, {"username": "username", "key": "key"}, ...]
```

i tried json.dump and json.dumps but it doesn't worked for me, please help me

this is the code that i written for now:

```
import json

username = input('Username to put in the keys file: ')
key = input('Key to put in the keys file: ')

uak = {"username": username, "key": key}

with open('keys.json', 'r') as r:
    data = json.load(r)

with open('keys.json', 'w') as w:
    json.dump(data, w)
```

Comment: 1. Load the json file. 2. `append()` the new user input (`uak`) to the list (`data`). 3. Save the json. You already have 1 and 3 so insert 2 in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `keys.json` file's  content initially must be equal to `[]` that matchs an empty json array to append your objects at runtime, then you have to add your `{"username": username, "key": key}` json object to your `data` list with the append method like below:

```
#keys.json is initialized with [] 

import json

username = input('Username to put in the keys file: ')
key = input('Key to put in the keys file: ')

uak = {"username": username, "key": key}

with open('keys.json', 'r') as r:
    data = json.load(r)

with open('keys.json', 'w') as w:
    data.append(uak)
    json.dump(data, w)
```